# rake rails:update:bin Error with activesupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying run my RoR application, but, when I run rails server, display the error:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 application  Generate the Rails application code
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

And if I run the command update:

```
$ rake rails:update:bin 
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.bundle
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: It looks like you may have the 'rmagick' gem in your Gemfile. If so, you should switch it out for [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick). The rmagick gem is notorious for causing issues with Rails.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem, I had compile all the imagemagick and link the references with brew link. @infused